# i3 4.17 ignores config file

Tags: i3

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, which brought in a new version of i3: 4.17. The config file remains untouched and in the same place: `~/.i3/config`. However i3 is ignoring it. Should it be moved to a different path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i3 now looks at `~/.config/i3/config` before `~/.i3/config`, so if the former exists, the latter will be ignored.

One possible fix is to replace `~/.config/i3/config` with a symlink to `~/.i3/config`, or move the latter to `~/.config/i3/config`.